# Three bishops vs. rook endgame

Tags: endgame, bishop-endgame, rook-and-minor-endgame

Can a rook force a draw against three bishops?

One of the bishops is on a different coloured square than the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a win for the three bishops. However, it can be a rather long process.

The tablebase I consulted says that in this position with White to move, the best move for White is Kd3, which is a win for Black with DTZ of 87.

```
[FEN "8/2kb4/8/8/8/2K1b2b/8/3R4 w - - 4 3"]
```

In fact, in some positions, the 50 move rule will trigger, which could result in a draw with best play. Here, Kd5 results in a DTZ of 101:

```
[FEN "k7/3b4/8/8/2K5/7b/5b2/1R6 w - - 1 1"]
```

Comment: It seems replacing the bishop with a knight (ensuring the other two bishops are on differently-coloured squares) also forces mate. A particularly difficult one is white[Kc3, Rh8] and black[Ka1, Bd1, Ba7, Na8] with black to move and win with DTZ of 133.

Comment: And to be clear, the example I selected almost certainly isn't the longest DTZ. I just put the pieces down wherever.

Comment: Your "DTZ of 133" comment made me try some other positions... yeah, sometimes the DTZ goes above 100, meaning the side with the rook could potentially get a draw by 50 move rule. I edited that possibility in.